# Need for diodes in opamp comparator

Tags: operational-amplifier

I was reading through basic op amp comparator wherein 2 clamping diodes are used. This limits the differential voltage to 0.7V. How does it help? [image]

Comment: You need to show schematic or reference material. Without that this vague question will be closed.

Comment: This question needs more work, what basic op amp comparator? Show a schematic or the file, your question will most likely be closed for being unclear. You can get it re opened after you edit it.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please quickly realise that this is not a free design house, homework-answering service or an on-line technical encyclopedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your questions shows that you've done as much as you possibly could on your own - which your post doesn't, I'm afraid. Please revise your question showing your work and findings so far in detail. Or delete the question if Internet searches give you your answer anyway. Again, a warm welcome to the site.

Comment: Added circuit for reference. I am talking about protection diodes in the circuit

Comment: Good, a revised and clear question :-) Removed VTC

Answer (score 7):

The circuit shown is actually a bad example of a sometimes good idea. If you look up the data sheet for the LM741, you'll see that the maximum allowed differential input (the difference between the two inputs) is +/-30 volts, while the maximum input voltage on any input is +/- 15 volts. So as long as the inputs are within the maximum range their difference is also within the maximum limit.

And I can't help but add that the circuit is not good practice in that it uses a general-purpose op amp as a comparator. For any sort of high performance, you should always use a dedicated comparator - but then again, for any sort of high performance *anything* you don't use a 741. But I digress.

Using protection diodes is actually a good idea for op amps which are expected to saturate, that is, drive their outputs close to the power supply voltages. Op amps depend on their input transistors being well-matched and well-behaved in order to produce good results. Driving the inputs to a large voltage difference is bad in both departments, and some op amps can require milliseconds to fully recover when the voltages get back to normal. So high-speed, high-precision circuits which experience large transients can benefit. A good example of such a circuit is the output amplifier for a high-speed DAC.

Real comparators, in contrast, are generally designed with large input differences in mind, so input diodes are not usually needed. The exception to this rule is a circuit which may produce input voltage higher than the power supply voltages, such as any circuit which monitors AC power lines. In this case, the diodes protect the circuit if a pathological input condition occurs.

Comment: I agree. Op must read da specs of device chosen and not think all devices are designs are compatible....It depends on technology used, Cin and GBW whether they choose to add internal Vbe or Vgs protection to 30V or not.

Answer (score 5):

Some op-amps, the bipolar type with super-Beta transistors in the front end, already have those diodes internally. As such they will conduct significant current if you apply a differential input voltage greater than a diode drop or two. This is another reason why op-amps in general don't make good comparators (though in some cases they are justified- such as when you just need a low performance comparator and an appropriate op-amp is there for free as part of a quad or dual).

The consequence of breaking down the B-E junction is that the beta of the transistors can be permanently reduced, and thus the bias current will increase.

An example of such an op-amp is the OP97. The [datasheet](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/OP97.pdf) says:

> The input pins of the OP97 are protected against large 
>   differential voltage by back-to-back diodes. Current-limiting 
>   resistors are not used to maintain low noise performance. If 
>   differential voltages above ±1 V are expected at the inputs, 
>   series resistors must be used to limit the current flow to a 
>   maximum of 10 mA. Common-mode voltages at the inputs are 
>   not restricted and may vary over the full range of the supply 
>   voltages used.

Some other op-amps have internal resistors and they may not provide much of a warning that significant current will flow for large differential input voltages.

In any case, in the particular example shown the diodes may shorten the response time because they prevent some internal nodes of the op-amp from saturating completely. The response time of a unity-gain compensated op-amp is going to be horrible anyway.

Comment: I agree all diodes add some input capacitance which must be weighed against desired slew rates for high impedance sources and some with low slew rate are better off internally protected.

Comment: With diodes clamping at +_0.5/0.6/0.7 volts, the front-end diffpair will be driven to full-one-way-or-other. IMHO For un-degenerated bipolar diffpair, +-0.1 volt maxes out the current steering. The UA715 has some degeneration, so its slewing toward null gets sensed long before VirtualGnd reaches ZERO overdrive and the UA715 will settle faster. And JFET/MOSFETs have other useful degrees-of-freedom in designing the diffpair "linear" input range. But +-0.5/0.6/0.7 overdrive? Fully overdriven in  all cases IMHO Its an unspecified spec but key for settling performance.

Answer (score 3):

By clamping, you minimize the stored charge at that node, what with Q = C*V.

That minimal charge is important for fast decisions.

In past decades, with custom-built successive-approximation ADCs, using an input resistor and feedback current-mode DAC (custom built), the junction of resistor and DAC showed the frantic binary-search waveform. Clamping that waveform as close to zero as possible was great trick for decision speedup.

I even investigated active-summing-node clamps, using matched arrays of transistors, to hold the summing-node within 10millivolts (not 600 milliVolts) of zero; unfortunately I was not yet aware of the Cmiller of my nulling circuit and put the project aside.

In an ADC, you know the timing needed, and a special active-clamp is usable; you can get (almost) the same benefit, with common-base clamps, in non-synchronous circuits, thusly:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f41v90.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If you want to save power and board area, but give up several hundred milliVolts of tight clamping, try one of these diodes

[image]

We used a lot of HP5082-2835. If you can keep the diode HOT, it clamps at 0.2 volts.

[image]

Unfortunately, the diode leads have HIGH PERMEABILITY ~~ 2,000, thus have high inductance. Dumet or Kovar is the brand name.

Answer (score 2):

Some Vbe reverse voltages are limited to -5V which can cause breakdown and possible thermal damage from low Z drivers to input.

Low capacitance diodes can result in differential V protection when output is saturated and input delta V may not be 0.

Comparators are a different design than OA's and have internal Vbe reverse diode protection built in and the Absolute max V differential input will reflect this as in the LM358.

Learn to understand all the specs in any datasheet!

Comment: What happens if diodes are not used?

Comment: Breakdown can be destructive; or if emitter-base junctions are the path, the injected current may degrade the bipolar noise figure.

Comment: Observe the specs Absolute Max. If it says +/-4.8V then trust this and ensure no long cable picks up a transient directly into the OA input and use diode protection. If protected by a local source IC which has limits on diffrential swing, then no protection needed. e.g. a linear inverting gain cct with negative feedback and bias to Vcc/2 for Vin+ needs no protection since input and feedback ought to never create a delta V input and saturate the output in a decent design. So R ratio and input swing can limit Vin- - Vcc/2